# Select Specific Cell After Pressing TAB

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do a simple thing, after pressing TAB, instead of going to the cell right to the active, I want vba to select a specific range.

I tried the code below, but when I press tab, Excel returns an error as if there's no Macro for this, but if I open the macros list and execute this particular, the cell is selected.

```
Sub TabPress()
With Sheet1
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}", Range("E10:F10").Select
    
End With
End Sub
```

After this, I wanted to insert an IF statement to cicle between two ranges, it'd be something like this:

```
Sub TabPress()
With Sheet1
    If ActiveCell = Range("E10:F10") & Application.OnKey "{TAB}", Then
    Range("F8").Select
End If
    If ActiveCell = Range("F8") & Application.OnKey "{TAB}", Then
    Range("E10:F10").Select        
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Now, obviously this second one didn't work, but could anyone help me make this work? I'm a beginner on VBA, but I learn fast, so any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: FYI your `With` statements aren't "linking" to the ranges. Add a `.` before `Range()` to make sure it's the correct sheet.  Also, does this question help? ["How to detect if a specific key was pressed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940931/how-to-detect-if-a-specific-key-was-pressed)

Comment: [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-Ni3nqxZI0) .. It works if the workbook is already saved. [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34153682/9808063) .. Remember to set it back to normal/ default. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things not right in what you're trying to do.

First, it seems like you're trying to use `&` like a logical operator. In VBA, `&` is a string concatenation operator. For logical or bitwise "and", use `And`.

And it seems like you're trying to use the `Application.OnKey` method like a condition. You can't do that: it doesn't return a value.

In your code above `TabPress` wants to be the action taken when tab is pressed. It seems like you're trying to instruct Excel to take certain action on a tab key event, and telling it that *when that key event occurs*. That doesn't work. You need to have one procedure that calls `Application.OnKey` to tell Excel to start watching for tab key events, and then a *separate* procedure that is the action taken when the tab key event does occur.

You need to call `Application.OnKey` in a procedure that itself is triggered by an event — specifically, an event marking the start of a session context in which you want the key behaviour to start applying. It could be a manual trigger—you explicitly run the procedure that calls `Application.OnKey`. Or it could be an automatic trigger, such as when a particular notebook is activated. You also want to make sure to have a trigger when the session context ends, such as when the workbook is deactivated, that restores the original behaviour. For this automatic behaviour, you'd use built-in *event procedures*.

For example, if you want something to be done whenever a particular workbook is open, then you'd add a `Workbook_Open` event procedure in the `ThisWorkbook` module. To have something done when a workbook is closed, you'd add `Workbook_BeforeClose` in `ThisWorkbook`.

For `OnKey`, you probably want the action to occur when the workbook is *active*, not simply when it's open. (If when open, Excel will try to apply the `OnKey` action in other workbooks as well, and they probably won't have the code triggered by the `OnKey` event, so you'll get an error.) For `OnKey`, you probably want to use [`Workbook_Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.activate(even)) and [`Workbook_Deactivate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.deactivate) to set and clear the `OnKey` behaviour.

Now let's look at the [`Application.OnKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) method. It expects for the second argument the *name of a sub procedure*, not some statements. So, you need a separate (third) sub that does the action you want to happen when tab is pressed. This can be `TabPress` (corrected, so it's not calling `Application.OnKey`).

Now, it appears there is a bug in Excel that affects how it finds the procedure that's referenced in the `OnKey` method. That's the Error you're probably encountering. To work around this issue, there are two things you need to do:

- Put the `TabPress` procedure *in a worksheet module*, not in the workbook module. (At least, I couldn't figure out how to get it to work in the workbook module.)
- In the `OnKey` method call, you need to specify the worksheet module as part of the procedure name.

With that in mind, here's what you could put in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```vb
Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "!Sheet1.TabPress"
End Sub

Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}"
End Sub
```

Now add `TabPress` in the Sheet1 module. (Of course, if your worksheet has a different name, you need to use that name in the `OnKey` method call.)

Within `TabPress`, you want an `if` statement that checks what the current selection is, and you're trying to use `ActiveCell = Range("E10:F10")` as the condition. I don't think that will work: while multiple cells can be *selected*, there is only ever one cell that is *active*. So `ActiveCell` won't ever correspond to a range of multiple cells. I think what you want to use is `Selection`.

Now, to compare a selection location with a specified range, I think you need to compare *addresses*, not range objects. (Btw, when comparing two objects, use the [`Is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/is-operator) operator; `=` is used for comparing non-object values.) And when comparing addresses, include `$`s in the address spec:

```vb
Sub TabPress()
    If Selection.Address = "$E$10:$F$10" Then
        Range("F8").Select
    Else
        Range("E10:F10").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

With the workbook build-in event procedures and this as the action for tab key events, this does what I think you want.

Comment: this is only useful once and then it doesnt work for the rest of the life of the workbook how can i reset it?

Comment: also it ignores if certain cell selected, no matter which cell is selected it always jumps back to the origanl select.